# Where can i download the Windows Core Audio Library ? (dll file/s)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I saw the link for this api in some other answers:

[Windows Core Audio Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

But i can't find there where/how to download the api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Core Audio is a part of Windows OS since Vista. So you don't need to download it. It either already exists in your system (if you have Vista or higher) or is not supported.

If you need header files to write your program against them - download latest Windows SDK from Microsoft's website, it should contain everything that is required to use this API.

Also, MSDN contains info on which header file from SDK you should include to use any particular API. E.g.: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371395%28v=vs.85%29.aspx (see Requirements section).

If you need to use Core Audio from C# (as your tags suggest), you should either [create a COM-wrapper yourself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404285%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or use [someone else's](https://netcoreaudio.codeplex.com/).